# How to invite an authed facebook user apps and game group using facebook api?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-game-groups

i am working on a problem here. I want to add any person who visits my website to a closed group on facebook. For this i have create an app and asked for permissions but even after it show status = connected the app is not inviting users and returns an #3 OAuthException. I am doing this using javascript SDK only.

Here is the snippet of my javascript code file which i created by following this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) .

```
(function(d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;  }
            js = d.createElement('script');
            js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID',                        
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });


  FB.login(function(response) {
      var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      FB.api('/GROUP_ID/members'+response.authResponse.userID, 'post', {"access_token": accessToken}, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
      });
  }, {scope: 'user_groups,friends_groups'});
```

*As you guys marked my answer as duplicate, i am editing my question from here.* Please at least confirm that, if you guys are sure that inviting a user to a group is not possible. I already visited that link which is mentioned. It says that inviting a user to a group is not possible, but according to the [developer's document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) it is said that :-

> Applications can invite users to a group by issuing a POST request to
>   /GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID with an app access_token.
>
> Note that user being invited must be a user of the application. The
>   user will be sent a notification saying that they have been invited to
>   the group. The notification will take them to the group page.

So kindly reply, if you have any idea about it.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> App and Game Groups is currently in Beta

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/

1. User must already be authorized to inviting app.
2. Application Access Token must be used for invites.

Applications can invite users to a group by issuing a POST request to /GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID with an app access_token.

> Note that user being invited must be a user of the application. The
>   user will be sent a notification saying that they have been invited to
>   the group. The notification will take them to the group page. Users
>   can only be invited once. Subsequent invites will fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shawn. You have been a great help to me. Thanks a tonn.